# Ruby On Rails and VIM

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, vim

What is the best IDE plugin for VIM?

I'm looking for a VIM plugin that

- is easy to use and install
- supports auto-completion
- supports jumping to method/class definitions
- does not change the files of my Rails project (I'm co-working in a software project where not everybody uses VIM)
- should be compatible with the latest Rails versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rails.vim** is the best for now

https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567

Answer (score 0):

There's a few auto-completion-ish plug-ins around for vim, but probably the most straightforward one is just the built-in "keyword completion".  It does not know any particular language, but if you use, eg, `set complete=.,b,k`, it will scan the current file (.), other loaded files (b), and any files set as dictionaries (use `set dictionary=/some/file`) for matches.  Add that stuff to your .vimrc. To use completion, type a couple letters and hit ctrl-p in INSERT mode, you'll get a pop-up of cantidates.  It's unobtrusive and easy to use.  For more info on `complete` try `:help E535`.

WRT to class/method indexing, there's the taglist plugin:

http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/feature.html

Which will index a bunch of languages including ruby (nice if you are are working in js at the same time, etc).  It will take about 30 seconds to figure out.  Slightly more awkward to use in the pure ncurses version (ie, not gvim) if you can't use the mouse to switch windows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an info about how to use VIM as ror ide.

http://biodegradablegeek.com/2007/12/using-vim-as-a-complete-ruby-on-rails-ide/

Moreover following plugins can be useful.

NERDTree
FuzzyFinder
snipMate